# Python 3.6 no module named 'gspread' - pyinstaller compiled executable

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have compiled some python code using pyinstaller, working out well however upon running the actual executable, I get the error as mentioned in title.

What I have tried to fix this:

```
--paths=directoryofgspreadmodule 
# still got the same error.
--hidden-import=gspread
# Samething
```

overall command:

```
python pyinstaller.py -F MyCode.py --paths=directoryofgspreadmodule --onefile
```

as a side note, I also am using matplotlib and the executable seemed to come out with 200Mb, is this normal?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Check to see if the gspread module was packaged but placed in the wrong spot. I had this problem with dll in my app. You could try adding --debug to the command for additional output information... also you might try looking in the %TEMP%\MEI... directory where the executable is unpacked. If its not there then you at least you narrowed it down

Comment: I could not find it in %TEMP%\MEI, however when looking through "warnMain" (called my python code "main") I found: missing module named gspread - imported by Main

Answer (score 0):

Never-mind this was my own bad. I set --paths= within the directory itself, no wonder it couldn't find it (as mentioned above)